# Javascript not working in JQuery loaded div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, popup

I load pages into a div. I can't execute javascript code in `page1.php`. How can I execute code when I load a page in to a div? Thanks for your help

```js
// <![CDATA[
function hide(id) {
  var divObject = document.getElementById(id);
  divObject.style.display = "none";
}

function show(id) {
    var divObject = document.getElementById(id);
    divObject.style.display = "block";
  }
  // ]]>
  -- >
  // <![CDATA[
  function fthrkl() {
    var objemiz;
    /*@cc_on @*/
    /*@if (@_jscript_version >= 5 ) try { objemiz = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP" ); } 
    catch (e ) { 
    try { objemiz = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP" ); } 
    catch (E ) { objemiz = false; } 
    }@end @*/
    if (!objemiz && typeof XMLHttpRequest != 'undefined') {
      try {
        objemiz = new XMLHttpRequest();
      } catch (e) {
        objemiz = false;
      }
    }
    return objemiz;
  }

function git(degerler, syf, alanadi) {
  gonder = new fthrkl();
  gonder.onreadystatechange = function() {
    document.getElementById(alanadi).innerHTML = "<div class=yukle_pencere><div class=yukle><img src=images/load.gif align=center ></div><div class=yukle_yazi>Yükleniyor</div></div>";
    if (gonder.readyState == 4) {
      document.getElementById(alanadi).innerHTML = gonder.responseText;

      function fthrkl() {};
    }
  }
  gonder.open('GET', syf + '?' + degerler, true);
  gonder.send(null);
}

function git2(degerler2, syf2, alanadi2) {
  gonder2 = new fthrkl();
  gonder2.onreadystatechange = function() {
    document.getElementById(alanadi2).innerHTML = "<center><img src=/images/loading.gif border=0 align=center ></center>";
    if (gonder2.readyState == 4) {
      document.getElementById(alanadi2).innerHTML = gonder2.responseText;

      function fthrkl() {};
    }
  }
  gonder2.open('GET', syf2 + '?' + degerler2, true);
  gonder2.send(null);
  location.reload();
}

function git3(degerler3, syf3, alanadi3) {
  gonder3 = new fthrkl();
  gonder3.onreadystatechange = function() {
    document.getElementById(alanadi3).innerHTML = "<center><img src=/images/loading.gif border=0 align=center ></center>";
    if (gonder3.readyState == 4) {
      document.getElementById(alanadi3).innerHTML = gonder3.responseText;

      function fthrkl() {};
    }
  }
  gonder3.open('GET', syf3 + '?' + degerler3, true);
  gonder3.send(null);
}

function git5(degerler5, syf5, alanadi5) {
  gonder5 = new fthrkl();
  gonder5.onreadystatechange = function() {
    document.getElementById(alanadi5).innerHTML = "<label class='control-label'>Firma Ünvanı</label><div class='controls'><input type='text' class='input-xlarge' id='FirmaAdi' name='FirmaAdi' value='Firma Seçmediniz' disabled><button class='btn' type='button'><i class='icon-refresh'></i> </button></div>";
    if (gonder5.readyState == 4) {
      document.getElementById(alanadi5).innerHTML = gonder5.responseText;

      function fthrkl() {};
    }
  }
  gonder5.open('GET', syf5 + '?' + degerler5, true);
  gonder5.send(null);
}

function git4(degerler4, syf4, alanadi4) {
    gonder4 = new fthrkl();
    gonder4.onreadystatechange = function() {
      document.getElementById(alanadi4).innerHTML = "<div class='alert alert-info'><i class='fa fa-info-circle'></i> Yükleniyor...</div>";
      if (gonder4.readyState == 4) {
        document.getElementById(alanadi4).innerHTML = gonder4.responseText;

        function fthrkl() {};
      }
    }
    gonder4.open('GET', syf4 + '?' + degerler4, true);
    gonder4.send(null);
    location.reload();
  }
  // ]]>
  -- >
```

```css
#overlay {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 9999999;
  background: url(../panel/img/popupb.png);
  display: none;
}
.pencere {
  position: absolute;
  width: 500px;
  margin: -100px 0px 0px -250px;
  top: 25%;
  left: 50%;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 0px;
  z-index: 99999999;
}
.pencere_ic {
  font-weight: normal;
  border-color: #01a161;
  background: #FFF;
  border-radius: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  border-width: 3px 0px 0px 0px;
  border-top: 3px solid #01a161;
}
.yukle_pencere {
  margin: auto;
  width: 250px;
  height: 70px;
  background-color: white;
  font-weight: normal;
}
.yukle {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  z-index: 9000;
}
.yukle_yazi {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: gray;
}
.yukle_pencere1 {
  margin-bottom: 18px;
  display: block;
}
.yukle1 {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
  z-index: 9000;
}
.yukle_yazi1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<button type="submit" class="sppb-btn sppb-btn-primary" onclick="$('body').scrollTop(0);show('pencere');show('overlay');git('uid=666&odemetur=0&durum=0&makbuz='+document.getElementById('makbuz').value+'&tutar='+document.getElementById('tutar').value+'&adne='+document.getElementById('adne').value+'&OdemeYil='+document.getElementById('OdemeYil').value+'&aciklama='+document.getElementById('aciklama').value+'&OdemeAy='+document.getElementById('OdemeAy').value,'ajax/tahsilat.asp','pencere');"><i class="fa"></i> Gönder</button>

<div class="pencere" id="pencere"></div>
<div id="overlay"></div>
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: you must be loading jquery library at bottom so it wont recognise $

Comment: can you please specify which part of code is not working. It is hard to debug the entire code

Comment: any given errors in console?

Comment: The code works. But JavaScript is not enabled in pop-up div.

Comment: <script src="../js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>